# Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 60332

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

first i want to fetch data from my localhost in MySQL Workbench, I already create dummy database and put the table inside it, but when I did going to fetch data using mysql1 package I got an error

```
E/flutter (15888): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 60332
E/flutter (15888): #0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:694:35)
E/flutter (15888): #1      _NativeSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:960:12)
E/flutter (15888): #2      _RawSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1843:26)
E/flutter (15888): #3      RawSocket.connect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:21:23)
E/flutter (15888): #4      BufferedSocket.defaultSocketFactory
buffered_socket.dart:72
E/flutter (15888): #5      BufferedSocket.connect
buffered_socket.dart:89
E/flutter (15888): #6      MySqlConnection.connect
single_connection.dart:139
E/flutter (15888): #7      Mysql.getConnection
mysql.dart:11
E/flutter (15888): #8      _MyHomePageState._getCustomer
main.dart:37
E/flutter (15888): #9      _InkResponseState.handleTap
ink_well.dart:1096
E/flutter (15888): #10     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback
recognizer.dart:253
E/flutter (15888): #11     TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp
tap.dart:627
E/flutter (15888): #12     BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp
tap.dart:306
E/flutter (15888): #13     BaseTapGestureRecognizer.acceptGesture
tap.dart:276
E/flutter (15888): #14     GestureArenaManager.sweep
arena.dart:163
E/flutter (15888): #15     GestureBinding.handleEvent
binding.dart:464
E/flutter (15888): #16     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent
binding.dart:440
E/flutter (15888): #17     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent
binding.dart:336
E/flutter (15888): #18     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately
binding.dart:395
E/flutter (15888): #19     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent
binding.dart:357
E/flutter (15888): #20     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue
binding.dart:314
E/flutter (15888): #21     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket
binding.dart:295
E/flutter (15888): #22     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:164:13)
E/flutter (15888): #23     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:361:7)
E/flutter (15888): #24     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:91:31)
E/flutter (15888):
```

I tried a lot of reference that told me to change the port that I have in this code into 127.0.0.1, or 10.0.2.2 and still got the same error

```dart
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class Mysql {
  Future<MySqlConnection> getConnection() async {
    var settings = ConnectionSettings(
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        db: 'company');
    return await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
  }
}
```

and this is the code that I used to fetch data from user

```dart
 void _getCustomer() {
    db.getConnection().then((conn) {
      String sql = 'select mail from company.customer where id = 10;';

      conn.query(sql).then((results) {
        for (var row in results) {
          setState(() {
            mail = row[0];
            print(row[0]);
          });
          print(results);
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

and there nothing being printed there

this is my configuration of SQL server and it is running
[image]

tried to restart the SQL server and still got the same result. but when I try to use the same command at my Workbench is surely gave me a response

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The mobile Apps dont understand local hosts you can try this fix:

-open cmd as Administrator

- run `ipconfig`

3 copy IPv4 Address from cmd

4 replace 'localhost' with your IPv4 Address

5 run your app after flutter clean

Comment: im using emulator

Comment: you can also try this fix on emulator

Comment: still the same error i got there `Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 192.168.1.11, port = 33250`, I got the IP address from `ifconfig` on mac and in `inet` section of en0